Properties of graded ring inherited by zero grade component
I am trying to solve Exercise 5.3.D in Vakil's FOAG (27 July 2024 version), so I have to prove that quasiprojective $A$-scheme must be of finite type over $A$.
(If you don't want to read all the prelude, feel free to skip it and go directly to list of my questions in the final paragraph)
Here quasiprojective $A$-scheme means open quasicompact subscheme of $\mathrm{Proj}~S_{\bullet}$, where $S_{\bullet}$ is a finitely generated graded ring over ring $A$.
A scheme $X$ is called of finite type over ring $A$ if it can be covered by a finite collection of open affine subschemes: $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{Spec}~B_i$, where each $B_i$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra.
Note that property of being a locally finite type over $A$ (by locally we mean that we do not need the finiteness of affine cover) is affine-local, so it is enough to check that $\mathrm{Proj}~S_{\bullet}$ is of finite type over $A$, when $S_{\bullet}$ is finitely generated ring over $A$.
My idea is to cover $\mathrm{Proj}~S_{\bullet}$ with $D_{+}(f_i) \cong \mathrm{Spec}~((S_{\bullet})_{f_i})_{0}$ and to show that $((S_{\bullet})_{f_i})_{0}$ must be finitely generated algebras over $A$. (Here the $0$-subscript denotes the subring of all homogenous elements of degree $0$ and $f_i$ are generators of $S_{\bullet}$ as a graded ring over A)
It is quite evident that $(S_{\bullet})_f$ is finitely generated over $A$. But I am stuck at showing that its zero grade subring $((S_{\bullet})_f)_{0}$ is finitely generated over $A$ too.
Remember that in general case a subring of finitely generated ring must not be finitely generated!
Finally, here are my questions:

If $~T_{\bullet}$ is finitely generated graded ring over ring $A$, is it true that its zero grade subring $~T_0$ will be finitely generated algebra over $A$ too?
What about other ring properties, e.g. being noetherian? Can you make a list of properties of graded rings that are always inherited by their zero grade subring?
If some of the previous questions have negative answers, what is the right way to solve this exercise?


To give a quick answer to (1), for $T_\bullet$ to be a finitely generated graded ring over a ring $A$, each graded piece $T_n$ must be a finitely generated $A$-module. So, $T_0$ is a finitely generated $A$-module too, and is thus a finitely generated algebra over $A$.

@walkar I can't see why $T_0$ must be finitely generated $A$-module: if $f_i$ are generators of degree $0$, we can take all their finite products, which are infinitely many, and they seem to be linearly independent. What's going wrong?

A generating set for $T_\bullet$ over $A$ must generate $T_0$ over $A$, or else it can't generate the entire ring.
